# Routing prefix as follows the Virtual Host

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony

I've got a Symfony application that have 2 bundles: a public bundle (callable by the URL /public/blahblah/test/...) and an API bundle (callable by the URL /api/getIt).
I created 2 subdomains with 2 vhosts, one for the public, one for the api.

Now, I'm looking for a RewriteRule or something else in Symfony that let http://api.mydomain.com be equivalent as http://mydomain.com/api for Symfony, and the same for public.

In casual web, It would be possible by defining the DocumentRoot of the Virtual Host, but I have no idea how to do that being compatible with the Symfony routing system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Available since symfony 2.2 this can be solved using [host-matching routes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/hostname_pattern.html).

**app/config/routing.yml**

```
api_subdomain:
    resource: "@YourApiBundle/Resource/config/routing.yml" # your API's routes
    prefix:   "/"
    host:     "api.mydomain.com"

api:
    resource: "@YourApiBundle/Resource/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   "/api"
    defaults: "mydomain.com"
```

Now you only need one vhost just add `api.mydomain.com` as an alias to your vhost configuration.

**vhost config** (Apache)

```
ServerName:  mydomain.com
ServerAlias: api.mydomain.com
```