# Symfony 2 - can't configure application for hosts

Tags: symfony, routes, resources, host

I have problem with setting hosts for my symfony application. For now we have one domain, let's sey it was domain.pl for all four languages. So rule in YML was:

```
front_common:
    resource: "@FrontCommonBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /{_locale}
    defaults: { _locale: pl }
    requirements:
        _locale:  "[a-z]{2}"

front_common_locale:
    path: /
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:urlRedirect
        _locale: pl
        path: /pl
        permanent: true
```

So if someone enters domain.pl, he/she will be redirected to domain.pl/pl. Other pages was domain.pl/en, domain.pl/de and so on...

Now we get another domain, let's say domain.eu, that should show only english version, so domain.eu show english, others still redirects to /pl /de etc. My routing now looks this way:

```
front_common_eu:
    host:     domain.eu
    resource: "@FrontCommonBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
    defaults: { _locale: en }

front_common:
    resource: "@FrontCommonBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /{_locale}
    defaults: { _locale: pl }
    requirements:
        _locale:  "[a-z]{2}"

front_common_locale:
    path: /
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:urlRedirect
        _locale: pl
        path: /pl
        permanent: true
```

When I enter domain.pl it works fine, and redirects me to /pl. But when I enter domain.eu it works the same, it redirects me to /pl. If I remove fron_common_locale route, I've got 404. Help, what am I doing wrong?

PS. According to this: [Routing prefix as follows the Virtual Host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834301/routing-prefix-as-follows-the-virtual-host) it should work...

Answer (score 0):

Replace `_locale` on `front_common_locale` with:

```
_locale: pl|en
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't work. I found that one resource can't be included twice. I've also found, that bundle: https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle is answer to my question how to hide default language, so the topic is resolved.