# Symfony allow files access in Resources folder .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony

I need to open access to the following folder for everyone:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\app\Resources\export
```

but I get 403 Forbidden error. I tried many variants but still no luck. My .htaccess which is located at

```
C:\xampp\htdocs
```

is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

# Explicitly disable rewriting for front controllers
RewriteRule ^app_dev.php - [L]
RewriteRule ^app.php - [L]

# Fix the bundles folder
RewriteRule ^bundles/(.*)$ /myapp/web/bundles/$1  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ /myapp/web/js/$1  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ /myapp/web/css/$1  [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myapp/web/app.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [E=SYMFONY_ENV:prod]
```

Any ideas would be welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that DocumentRoot of your server is pointing to `/web` directory and `/app` directory is out of scope. Maybe you can solve it using an alias:

```
Alias /export "C:/xampp/htdocs/myapp/app/Resources/export"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/myapp/app/Resources/export">
    Options Indexes
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

When using `alias` you must to prefix the route to the resource with the alias name.

For example for getting the resoource test.jpg located in:

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/myapp/app/Resources/export/test.jpg
```

Your request should be like:

```
http://yourServerName/export/test.jpg
```

The problem of this type of routes is that Symfony routing can't managed it because there are out of server scope, but you can use host-matching, see this question:

[Routing prefix as follows the Virtual Host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834301/routing-prefix-as-follows-the-virtual-host/19836762#19836762)

If you use alias remember enable alias module if it is disabled.

Hope it helps.